# Macro/VBA: highlight rows based on 2 conditions

Tags: excel, vba

Objective is to highlight rows that meet two different conditions:

1. If column A is equal to the previous workday (taking into consideration of holidays mentioned in the Reference sheet)
2. If column B is not equal to "AA"

I have the following code, but am unable to get appropriate rows highlighted (no rows get highlighted due to condition #1 not being met):

```
Sub code()

    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lrow
    If Cells(i, "A").Value = "=WORKDAY(today(),-1,Reference!$A$2:$A$12)" And Cells(i, "B").Value <> "AA"  Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Next i
  
End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest you make a separate function to find the previous working day, then use that result in the comparison.

Comment: Instead of `Cells(i, "A").Value = "=WORKDAY(...)"` what about `Cells(i, "A").Value = Application.Evaluate("WORKDAY(...)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub code()

    Dim i As Long, lrow As Long
    Dim objRangeHolidays As Range
    
    Set objRangeHolidays = Worksheets("Reference").Range("$A$2", "$A$12")
    
    lrow = Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    
    For i = 2 To lrow
      If CDate(Cells(i, "A").Value) = CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1, objRangeHolidays)) And Cells(i, "B").Value <> "AA" Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
      End If
    Next i
  
    Set objRangeHolidays = Nothing
  
End Sub
```

Your original code does not work as  `"=WORKDAY(today(),-1,Reference!$A$2:$A$12)"` is a literal string on VBA, not a function call.

We use `CDate()` function to make our cell values comparable with `WorksheetFunction.Workday()` function.

`WorksheetFunction.Today()` is the same as `Date()` in VBA.

`objRangeHolidays` holds holidays defined in `Reference` sheet.

This is my test result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Highlight Entire Rows

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub highlightPreviousWorkday()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "A2"
    Const sCritCol As String = "B"
    Const sCriteria As String = "AA"
    Const sColorIndex As Long = 6
    ' Holiday
    Const hName As String = "Reference"
    Const hFirst As String = "A2"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    wb.Activate ' `Evaluate` will fail if not active.
    
    ' Source
    Dim srg As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirst)
        Dim slCell As Range
        Set slCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If slCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set srg = .Resize(slCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Holiday
    Dim Holiday As String
    With wb.Worksheets(hName).Range(hFirst)
        Dim hlCell As Range
        Set hlCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If Not hlCell Is Nothing Then
            Holiday = ",'" & hName & "'!" _
                & .Resize(hlCell.Row - .Row + 1).Address
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Evaluation
    Dim evDate As Variant
    evDate = Evaluate("WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1" & Holiday & ")")
    
    ' Combine
    Dim drg As Range
    If VarType(evDate) = vbDouble Then
        Dim sCell As Range
        Dim sValue As Variant
        Dim sString As String
        For Each sCell In srg.Cells
            sValue = sCell.Value
            If VarType(sValue) = vbDate Then
                If CDbl(sValue) = evDate Then
                    sString = CStr(sCell.EntireRow.Columns(sCritCol).Value)
                    If sString <> sCriteria Then
                        Set drg = getCombinedRange(drg, sCell)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next sCell
    End If
  
    ' Color
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    srg.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    If Not drg Is Nothing Then
        drg.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = sColorIndex
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     
End Sub

Function getCombinedRange( _
    ByVal BuiltRange As Range, _
    ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range
        If BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
            Set getCombinedRange = AddRange
        Else
            Set getCombinedRange = Union(BuiltRange, AddRange)
        End If
End Function
```